# Having a Logic Error in my tile rendering code

Tags: tilemap, tiles, terrain-rendering, rust

I am a novice programmer.

In my program, I can render a 5000 x 500 map, but it renders incorrectly, instead of this :

,,~,,,,~,,,,,~,~,,,,,~~,,,~,,,~,,,~,,~~~,~~~,,,~,,,,~,~,,,~~,~,,~,~,~~,~,,,,,~,,~~,,~,,,,,,~,,,,,~,,~~,~,,,,,,,~,,,,~,~~,,,~,,,~,~~~,,~~~,,,,,,,,~,~~,,,,,~,,,,,~~,,,~,,~~,~~~,,,~,,~,~,,~,,,~~,~~,~,,~~~~~,~,,,,,~,~,~,~,,,,~~,,~,,,,,~,,,~,,~,,~,,,,~~,,,~,,,,,,,~,~,,,,,~,,,,~,~~,~,,,,,,,~,~~,,,,,~~,,,,,,~,~~~~,,~,,~,,,,~~,,,,~~,~~~,,~,~,,~~~~,,,~,,~,,,,~~,~,,,,,,,,,,,~,,~~,,~,~,~,,,,~~,,,,,,,,,~,,,~,,,,~~~,,,~,,~,,,,,~,,~,~~,,~~,,,,~,,~,,,,,,,,,,,,~~,,,,,,,,~,,~~,,,,~,,,~,,,,~,,,,~,,,,,,~,,,,,,~,~,,,,,,,~,,~~~,~~~~,,~~,~,~,~,,,~,~,,~,~~,~,,,,,,~,~,~,,,,~,,,~,,~,,~,,,,,~~~~,,,,,~,,,~~,,,~,,,,~~,~,~~,~,~~,~,~,~~~~,,,~,,,,,,~,,,,,,,~,,,,,~~,~~~,,~~,~~,~,,~,,~~~,,,,,,~~,~,~,,,,~,,,,,,,,,,~~,,,,~,,~,,~~,,,~,,,,~,~,,~,~,,,~~~~,~,,,,,,~~~,,~,,~~~,~~~,~,,~,,,~,,,,,,~~,,,,~,,,~~~,,~,~,,,,~~,~,,,,,,~,~,,~~~,,~~,,,~,,,,~,,~,~,,,,,,,,,~~,,,,,,~~,~~,,,~~~,,~,~,~,,,~~,,~,,,,,,,,,~,~,,~,,,,,,,~,,~,,~~~,~~,~,,,,~,~,,,,,,~,,,~,,,,,,,,,~,,~~~~,,,~~,,~,~,,~,,,,,,~~~~~~,,,~,,,,,~,,,,,,~,~,,,~~~,~,,~,~,,,,,,~,~,~,,,,,,~,,,~~,~,,,,,~~,~,~,,~,~~,,~,,,~,,,~~~,,,,,~,,~,~,,,~,~,,~~~~~~,,,,~,,,,,,,,,~,,,~,~~,,,,,,,,~,~~,,,,,~,,~~,,~,~~,,,,,~,,,~,,~~,~,,~,,,,,,,,,~~,~~,~,,,~,,~~,~~,,,~~,,~~~~,,,,,,,,~,,,,,~,~,,

which was generated using a random coin flip

it renders the tiles in weird lines like this:

```
~.~.~.~.
~.~.~.~.
~.~.~.~.
```

Here is the link to the [source code](https://play.rust-lang.org/)

Here is the rendering code:

```
    // Tile Renderer. 

    let screen_w_in_tiles: f32 = ceilf(screen_width() / 32.0);
    let screen_h_in_tiles: f32 = ceilf(screen_height() / 32.0);

    let center_tile_x = ((screen_width() / 2.0) - worldx as f32) / 32.0;
    let center_tile_y = ((screen_height() / 2.0) - worldy as f32) / 32.0;

    let lo_tile_x = floorf(center_tile_x - screen_w_in_tiles / 2.0); 
    let hi_tile_x = floorf(center_tile_x + screen_w_in_tiles / 2.0 + 2.0); 

    let lo_tile_y = ceilf(center_tile_y - screen_h_in_tiles / 2.0 - 2.0); 
    let hi_tile_y = ceilf(center_tile_y + screen_h_in_tiles / 2.0); 

    for i in lo_tile_x as usize..hi_tile_x as usize {
        for j in lo_tile_y as usize..hi_tile_y as usize {
            match world_data[i] {
                ','=> tile = grass,
                '*'=> tile = sand,
                '~'=> tile = water,
                '/'=> tile = ice,
                _=>   tile = unknown,
            }
            blit(tile, i as isize * 32 + worldx, j as isize * 32 + worldy, 32, 32);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks about right to me. I don't know where in the data that is… But you generated alternating grass and water, and you are using the x axis to query over that data. So the y does not matter. The result is columns. What output did you expect or want?

Comment: An output more like this: ~,,,~~~,,,,,~~~~~,,,,,~~~~~~~~~~~,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: The output i want is what it looks like from the saved data(i am using .bin files, if that helps)

Comment: Hang on. let me show you the output from the file

Comment: OK, i edited the question, to show you want output i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I think the code is doing what you are asking it to do. However, I have some idea of what you want. I might be wrong but… Well, you try and tell me.*

---

We have 1D data is `world_data`, but it is intended to be 2D. So we are going to map a 2D position of the world to a 1D position on `world_data`. In this particular case I'm going to do it by lines. *Because it is simple, be aware that there are other approaches to do this.*

Since we know the size of the first dimension (the width of the world) is 5000, we are going to assume we have lines of 5000 elements.

The y coordinate will tell us on which line we are, in other words how many lines we have to skip. The start of the y-th line is `5000 * y`. And the x coordinate will tell us the position inside the line. In other words, the position in `world_data` will be given by `5000 * y + x`. Or in you code:

```
world_data[5000 * j + i]
```

*I'll take the opportunity to suggest storing that 5000 in a variable or constant so you can change it in a single place.*

---

**Addendum**: I forgot, it is possible that goes out of bounds, so you will want a check, something like this:

```
for i in lo_tile_x as usize..hi_tile_x as usize {
    for j in lo_tile_y as usize..hi_tile_y as usize {
        let p = 5000 * j + i;
        if p < 0 || p >= world_data.len() {
            // perhaps draw some background here
            continue;
        }
        match world_data[p] {
            /* etc. */
        }
        // …
    }
}
```

---

**Addendum 2**: The above approach does not cut the edges of the world. We could do it with `lo_tile_x`, `lo_tile_y`, `hi_tile_x`, and `hi_tile_y` instead, by clamping them. I believe this works:

```
lo_tile_x = fmin(fmax(lo_tile_x, 0.0), 5000.0); # width
hi_tile_x = fmin(fmax(hi_tile_x, 0.0), 5000.0); # width
lo_tile_y = fmin(fmax(lo_tile_y, 0.0), 5000.0); # height
hi_tile_y = fmin(fmax(hi_tile_y, 0.0), 5000.0); # height
```

*I decided to go with libm::fmin and libm:fmax instead of clamp.*

Then it should not go out of bounds in the loop. Which means it should work without the fix from the prior addendum.

By the way, you could have the world loop instead. Which would be using the remainder. I hope it works like this:

```
lo_tile_x = ((lo_tile_x % 5000.0) + 5000.0) % 5000.0; # width
hi_tile_x = ((hi_tile_x % 5000.0) + 5000.0) % 5000.0; # width
lo_tile_y = ((lo_tile_y % 5000.0) + 5000.0) % 5000.0; # height
hi_tile_y = ((hi_tile_y % 5000.0) + 5000.0) % 5000.0; # height
```

*I know that is not pretty, but I can't figure out what is the correct modulo function in rust. Modulo as in modulo arithmetic, not remainder. The result should be positive.*

---

You can, by the way, use division and reminder to find the 2D coordinantes that will match a position from `world_data`. If do an integer division of the the 1D position by the width of the world, you will get the y coordinate, and x is the remainder of said division. *You may find this useful for generating the world, for example if you need to query a 2D noise function.*

Comment: I sort of understand what you are talking about, but when i run the code, it crashes with a index out of bound error: thread 'main' panicked at 'index out of bounds: the len is 25000000 but the index is 3907021250', src/main.rs:249:23

Comment: @MachoOnion see addendum. Edit: perhaps you want to draw some background in those out of bounds positions, now that I think about it.

Comment: It rendered no tiles when p was set to 5000, but i tweaked the value of from 5000 to 2, and i have gotten closer and closer each time i tweak it

Comment: But, when the value of p is over 30, it renders no tiles

Comment: @MachoOnion Is 30 triggering the bounds check? if you print `lo_tile_x`, `lo_tile_y`, `hi_tile_x`, `hi_tile_y` what do you get?

Comment: lo_tile_x prints 781250, so 30 * j + i probably equals 781250, i could be wrong

Comment: @MachoOnion Going by the `3907021250` from the error, that is the row number `3907021250 / 5000 = 781404` which should not be if the map is 5000 by 5000, perhaps `worldx` and `worldy` are too high? *Or too low? I see `-25000000` in the code you shared, perhaps I misunderstood those variables.*

Comment: let mut worldx: isize = -25000000;
let mut worldy: isize = -25000000; the numbers are negative so that the player is in the center of the map

Comment: Should we move the Discussion to chat?

Comment: @MachoOnion How is (-25000000, -25000000) the center of the map? The map is 5000 tiles by side, and 5000 * 32 = 160000 pixels by side. Anyway, go for a corner, put them at 0 and see what happens.

Comment: Putting worldx/y at 0, allows me to set P to 5000 and render it properly, it LOOKS like it is rendering properly, but i could be wrong, here is what it looks like https://postimg.cc/ZC74tzf4

Comment: @MachoOnion It looks good. It is not a corner. Is that the center? Hard to tell… You may use a non random map so you can tell where on it you are. Perhaps if you go for a smaller map you can write one manually. Well, you can try setting them to 160000. Does movement work? *And yes, I guess we can benefit from chat.*

Comment: It is at the top of the worldy, but in the center of worldx

Comment: OK, it is at the corner, but it did not look like it, because u had to walk a little way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134600/discussion-between-macho-onion-and-theraot).